# Proof: $ |||\frac{1}{2} AB + \frac{1}{2} BA||| \leq |||AB|||$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-equations

I am looking for a proof of the following:$$ |||\frac{1}{2} AB + \frac{1}{2} BA||| \leq |||AB|||$$

For positive hermitian matrices A and B, and a unitarily invariant norm $ |||\cdot|||$.

Comment: I think it is equivalent to prove that for any matrix $M$, we have
$$
|||M + M^*||| \leq |||2M|||
$$

Comment: I think that the [Fan dominance theorem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.1467.pdf) might be a helpful result here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\|\cdot\|$ is unitarily invariant, $\|M\|$ depends only on the singular values of $M$ and since $M^*$ has the same singular values as $M$, $\|M\|=\|M^*\|$. It remains to use the triangle inequality.

Comment: $$|||AB+BA||| = |||AB+B^*A^*||| = |||AB+(AB)^*||| \leq |||AB||| +|||(AB)^*||| = |||AB||| + |||AB||| = |||2AB||| $$

Comment: @Dani Exactly, the point is to know that a unitarily invariant norm is invariant w.r.t. conjugate transposition of the matrix because of its dependence solely on the singular values of the argument.

Comment: yes, that seems to be what I was missing, thanks for the help!!